# Nautilus doesn't allow me to access files

Tags: nautilus, permissions

I recently backed up the home partition of my hard drive, using an Ubuntu LiveCD and GParted.

Now every time I navigate to the partition a little padlock icon appears in the corner of the file/folder, and the only way to access the file is to use Nautilus as the superuser.

Answer (score 1):

- Start **nautilus as super-user**
- **Right-click** on said folder
- In the pop-up menu select "**Properties**"
- In the "Properties" dialogue select the tab called "**Permissions**"
- In the "Permissions" tab make sure that the **Owner of the folder is you** and that you have **read/write access**
- Than click "**Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files**"

Note: It also doesn't hurt to **set the right Group** here. You can do the same in the shell by typing:

```
sudo chown -R username:group /path/to/folder  # substitute your username and group for
sudo chmod -R ug+rw /path/to/folder           # "-R" means recursive - it will be applied to subfolders and files therein
```

[image: Permissions Tab in Folder Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Access home folder as superuser via terminal and then change owner with `chown`

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful, if you were to edit it to explain in detail how to do this (with the exact commands used to do it). Also, are these really separate steps? Why not just run a single `chown -R ...` command with `sudo`?